# check if two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, permutation

Check if two strings are permutations of each other, please help with the simple ARRAYS JS solution.
strings("sumit", "tiums").
Need to return true or false.

Comment: Sort the characters in the strings, then check if the results are equal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: `Array.from(str1).sort().toString() == Array.from(str2).sort().toString()` ?

Comment: function arraysMatch(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0; arr1.length < i; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true
};

let arePermutation = arraysMatch(string1.split("").sort(), string2.split("").sort())

console.log (arraysMatch("cat", "tac")) c

Answer (score 1):

you can split the string, and check if the arrays are the same:

```
let string1 = "sumit"
let string2 = "tiums"

var arraysMatch = function (arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0; arr1.length < i; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true
};

let arePermutation = arraysMatch(string1.split("").sort(), string2.split("").sort())
```

Comment: thank you, but the code is now working :(

Comment: @ysmdesigninc what do you mean with "is not working"? what error do you see?

Comment: I am so sorry if i sound stupid, I am the beginner and trying to understand. so the string1 is not defined, I did the concole.log(arraysMatch(("sumit", "tiums")

Comment: @ysmdesigninc check now